# is it possible to pass value from an ng.repeat to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have this section:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.img}}</td>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 dir="rtl" align="center">screenshot</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form ng-submit="submit()">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <img ng-src="{{data.img}}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">close</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </script>
                    <button ng-click="open()">open</button>
```

as it is, its not passing the value from `{{data.img}}` to the javascript which opens a modal window.
any ideas?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to properly solve this you'll need to pass in the column reference into the modal, else we can't determine which image to show.

```
$scope.open = function (imageKey) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'full',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, data, imageKey) {
            $scope.data='';
            $scope.data = data;

            $scope.getImage = function () {
                return $scope.data[imageKey];
            }

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('סגור');
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
                // access outer controller scope by using $scope.$parent
                return $scope.$parent.data;
            },
            imageKey: function() {
                return imageKey;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

On template (pass in the key you want to use):

```
<button ng-click="open('dioPlusImage')">פתח צילום מסך</button>
```

On modal template:

```
<img ng-src="{{getImage()}}>"
```

Comment: and what goes into the `img ng-src` in this type of solution ?

Comment: Added in answer. Sorry I accidentally added imageKey as function param

Comment: np =) Time for me to sleep!

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tagged bootstrap-modal so I assume you are using one.

You need to pass variable into modal by using the resolve key when you open the modal. The demo for modal should have that.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: { // here
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

On modal controller you get the variable as a service

```
controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items)
```

And then assign it to a scope variable so your modal template can see it

```
$scope.items = items;
```

---

With site provided in comment:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.open = function () {

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'full',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('סגור');
            };
        },
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
                // access outer controller scope by using $scope.$parent
                return $scope.$parent.data;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: NP! You'll need to use this pattern a lot as long as you deal with modals

Comment: Got a 404 on the link, any misspell?

Comment: Make sure you copy the entire link, the hyperlink doesn't seem to catch the entire link.

Comment: Also, You can see that I am only passing an extra string 'משרדיה' for the last column but it actually displays it in every window that is being opened.

Comment: You are using the template in a wrong way. The template should be declared outside of ng-repeat, so it doesn't get redeclared on every cell. This is also the reason why you are getting the extra string every where - the last template overwrite the others because they are sharing the same id. You can put it after where you import all the scripts before `</body>`

Comment: And, try not to send images by blob data, it makes the site load very slow. Make them available on separate paths, so the table can load first, then image only get loaded when modal is open.

Comment: So what should be left inside the ng-repeat?

Comment: And I would really like to put them on a separate path I simply couldn't figure out how to do that. I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Just moving the `<script>` block containing the template will do.

Comment: For image on separate path just put them on some other folder like /images and make sure you can access them by url.

Comment: A good place would be same level with app and css folder, then you can access the image by `image/filename`

Comment: I will change the images. with the script tag, if you look at the content, each script gets a different variable. the first gets data.dioPlusImage, the second gets inkDepotImage and so on. If I move the script outside, I will have to find a way to pass the variable name to the script.

Comment: A hacky way would be putting all possible values in the template and show only the available one
`<img ng-src="{{data.img1}}" ng-show="!!data.img1">
<img ng-src="{{data.img2}}" ng-show="!!data.img2">
<img ng-src="{{data.img3}}" ng-show="!!data.img3">`

Comment: A proper way would be standardising your key, or you can use a function to get the correct key `ng-src="{{getImgUrl()}}`

Comment: The hacky way doesnt work very well :) have a look at what happens now. its quite funny! Do you have an example for a `getImgUrl` function?